# Show $f'(0) = 3$ if $f$ is continuous at $0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)/x = 3$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm told that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x = 0$ and that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)/x = 3$.

How does it help me to say that $f$ can be differentiated and that $f'(0) = 3$?

Comment: I edited your question to use proper formatting, and changed the word "derived" to "differentiated". You can format things using TeX by enclosing them in dollar signs, for example typing \$x=0\$ gives $x=0$. In order to learn more complicated commands (such as for limits) you can right click on the TeX output in a post and select "Show Math As" and "TeX Commands".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Observe that
$$f(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}x=3\cdot 0=0$$
You want the limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=3$$
and so $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f^{\prime}(0)=3$

Comment: How did you make that equality between $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}x$$

Comment: oh, pardon me it's a trivial move

Comment: @Eran Because the value of the limit does not depend on the point $x=0$, and anywhere except $x=0$ we have $f(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}x$.